# Animar secuencia de botones en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo tres botones en una pagina, boton 1, boton 2 y boton 3. Además tengo una array con una secuencia [3,2,1,3]. Quiero aplicar una animacion a los botones en ese orden.Es decir, primero animar el boton 1. Cuando termine, el boton 2 ...y asi sucesivamente. El problema es que con mi código todas las animaciones se ejecutan al mismo tiempo...como puedo arreglarlo??

```js
var num=[3,2,1];
var index=0;


for(var i=0;i<num.length;i++){
  
  setTimeout(function anim(num){
  
  $("#b"+num).animate({ opacity: "1" }, 350 ).animate({ opacity: "0.5" }, 350);
  
},2000);
  
}
```

```css
button{
  
  opacity:0.5;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Btn 1</button>

<button id="b2" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Btn 2</button>

<button id="b3" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Btn 3</button>
```

Comment: Se ejecutan al mismo tiempo porque esta dentro de un pequeño ciclo, en realidad si se animan en el orden que tu deseas solo que es rapido y no alcanzas a identificarlo.

Comment: Y como puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: En estos momentos no puedo probar codigo ya que estoy desde un smartphone pero me imaginaba un setTimeout(function(){   //aqui dentro tu for }, 2000);  ahi son 2 segundos pero puedes agregarle mas

Comment: Ahí lo probe pero no funciona :(

Comment: Y si sacas el setTimeout y pones `$("#b"+num).animate({ opacity: "1" }, slow )` solamente sin el otro animate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código tiene un par de problemas:

1. Como todas las animaciones tienene el mismo tiempo para el `setTimeout` entonces todas se ejecutarán al mismo tiempo.
2. Cuando creas el `setTimeout`  estás pasando `num` como parámetro y luego lo usas como si fuera un valor concreto cuando realmente es una array.

Lo primero lo podrías solucionar dándole haciendo que el temporizador se incremente con cada iteración del bucle `for`; y lo segundo lo puedes solucionar pasando el valor en concreto que corresponda del array.

Con esos cambios quedaría así:

```js
var num=[3,2,1];
var index=0;


for(var i=0;i<num.length;i++){

  // asignamos el valor de la posición actual con un `let`
  let numval = num[i];
  
  setTimeout(function anim(){
    $("#b"+numval).animate({ opacity: "1" }, 350 ).animate({ opacity: "0.5" }, 350);
  }, 2000*(i+1)); // hacemos que haya una separación de 2 segundos entre cada animación

}
```

```css
button{
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="b1" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Btn 1</button>
<button id="b2" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Btn 2</button>
<button id="b3" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Btn 3</button>
```

---

Edición a partir de las comentarios de abajo.

El problema no es usar `num`, que sí estará disponible al ser una variable global; el problema es que estabas usando `num` sin nada más, cuando deberías usar `num[i]` que es el valor en concreto dentro del array; entonces cuando se llama al `setTimeout` el valor de `i` habría cambiado y el resultado no sería el esperado.

Eso ocurre porque `i`  se está declarando con un `var` entonces su ámbito es global y seguirá existiendo cuando se lance el `setTimeout` y con un valor (3) que no te vale. Lo mismo ocurriría si defino la variable `numval`.

Una solución más limpia sería definir el `i` con un `let` en lugar de con un `var`, entonces ya te funcionará (aunque tendrás que cambiar `num` por `num[i]`):

```js
var num=[3,2,1];
var index=0;


for(let i=0;i<num.length;i++){
  setTimeout(function anim(){
    $("#b"+num[i]).animate({ opacity: "1" }, 350 ).animate({ opacity: "0.5" }, 350);
  }, 2000*(i+1)); // hacemos que haya una separación de 2 segundos entre cada animación

}
```

```css
button{
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="b1" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Btn 1</button>
<button id="b2" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Btn 2</button>
<button id="b3" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Btn 3</button>
```

Comment: Gracias! Podrias decirme por que dentro de setTimeout no se puede acceder a la variable num, si num es una variable global?..Por que necesito usar let???

Comment: El problema no es usar `num`, que sí estará disponible al ser una variable global; el problema es que estabas usando `num`  sin nada más, cuando deberías usar `num[i]` que es el valor en concreto dentro del array; entonces cuando se llama al `setTimeout` el valor de `i` habría cambiado y el resultado no sería el esperado.

Comment: Intenté usar num[i] en vez de nunmval y no puedo acceder dentro de SetTimeout....

Comment: Eso ocurre porque, como pongo en mi comentario anterior: "_el valor de `i` habría cambiado y el resultado no sería el esperado_"

Comment: ahh.... y por que let numval y no var numbal.

Comment: Buena pregunta: si usas `val` el ámbito de la variable sería global y tendrías el mismo problema que con `i`. Al usar `let` el ámbito de la variable será únicamente el bucle `for` creando una especie de clausura con su valor. Otra opción más sencilla si lo prefieres, sería usar `let i` en lugar de `var i` en el bucle. Deja y edito la respuesta para ponerlo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49935/discussion-between-juan-and-alvaro-montoro).